# How can I collect key-value pairs of dictionaries into one large dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the following format:

```py
data = {
    'Bob': {
        'age': 12,
        'weight': 150,
        'eye_color': 'blue'
    },
    'Jim': {
        'favorite_food': 'cherries',
        'sport': 'baseball',
        'hobby': 'running'
    },
    'Tom': {
        'strength': 'average',
        'endurance': 'high',
        'heart_rate': 'low'
    }
}
```

What is the most Pythonic way to concatenate all of the dictionaries within dict into a new dictionary so that I would end up with something like the following:

```py
new_dict = {
    'age': 12,
    'weight': 150,
    'eye_color': 'blue',
    'favorite_food': 'cherries',
    'sport': 'baseball',
    'hobby': 'running',
    'strength': 'average',
    'endurance': 'high',
    'heart_rate': 'low'
}
```

Comment: Different ways of merging multiple dictionaries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-take-union-of-dictionari

Comment: @DarrylG. That one focuses on merging two dictionaries

Comment: @MadPhysicist -- but the answers are more general applying to multiple dictionaries.

Comment: @DarrylG Not without additional work in some cases

Comment: @MadPhysicist -- some answers seem straightforward to apply such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-take-union-of-dictionari/36263150#36263150

Comment: Agreed. That being said, this is not a straightforward duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) to build up the result, unioning one dictionary at a time:

```py
from functools import reduce

data = {
 'Bob' : { 'age': 12, 'weight': 150, 'eye_color': 'blue' },
 'Jim' : { 'favorite_food': 'cherries', 'sport': 'baseball', 'hobby': 'running' },
 'Tom' : { 'strength': 'average', 'endurance': 'high', 'hear_rate': 'low' }
}

result = reduce(lambda x, y: dict(**x, **y), data.values(), {})

print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
{'age': 12, 'weight': 150, 'eye_color': 'blue', 'favorite_food': 'cherries',
'sport': 'baseball', 'hobby': 'running', 'strength': 'average',
'endurance': 'high', 'hear_rate': 'low'}
```

On Python 3.9 or higher, you can use `lambda x: x | y`, `operator.or_`, or `dict.__or__` instead of `lambda x: dict(**x, **y)` if you're on Python 3.9 or higher. The latter two are from a suggestion by [Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988730/mad-physicist).

Comment: You can use `operator.or_` instead of the lambda, or `dict.__or__`, in 3.9+

Comment: Added to the original post with attribution.

Comment: Nice. I'd go with `dict.__or__`.

Comment: Any reason why? I thought it was normally bad practice to refer to dunder methods directly.

Comment: I feel that it makes it more clear what you're operating on. I suppose that's a personal idiosyncracy and `operator.__or__` is more pythonic

Comment: I never knew about ChainMap until now. Added to my answer

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a dictionary comprehension with a nested generator expression:

```
new_dict = {k: v for d in data.values() for k, v in d.items()}
```

Another way that's subtly different to to use [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap):

```
new_dict = collections. ChainMap(*data.values())
```

In this case, `new_dict` will not be a `dict`, but will quack like one just fine. Lookup will be a bit slower, but construction will be faster.